# Add text inside of the created files

Tags: python

So I have this code but I want to add text in a the files can you help me?

```
def createfile(num):

 with open(f'{name}{num+1}.txt', 'w') as file:
              pass

for num in range(number):
    createfile(num)

print('Alright')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for file i/o methods, especially `f.write()` and see if you can figure out a solution

Comment: hi patrick that doesnt work in my code